# Visual studio 2017 intellisense errors got mixed-up after crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

During a heavy code-refactoring session, I got a BSOD (Blue Screen Of Death). After restart, Visual Studio started to exhibit a strange intellisense problem:

(I was in the midst of refactoring a file with few thousand lines of code, with about a hundred errors)

After a build, the errors were at the right locations. After fixing any of them, all intellisense errors moved around like crazy and became unusable. I needed another F6 (build) and wait until things sort out.

I deleted every non source controlled folder in my solution, deleted the cache, ... Nothing seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out to be system time!!

After the crash, my system time went back a few hours.
After I fixed the time, the problem got solved.

PS: the reason for hour change is this: I've got a dual-boot Windows-Linux (Fedora). Fedora keeps the system time in UTC, while windows keeps it in Local time. So after any restart from Linux to Windows, I've got the wrong time.

Comment: So glad to hear that your issue is solved and thank you for your sharing, you can mark your reply as the answer, it just a reminder :)